# I do not see a Flutter version number or device info. Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am following the Flutter tut and I am trying to use Visual Studio Code and I do not see a Flutter version number or device info.  The [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/vs-code) says,

> If you do not see a Flutter version number or device info, your project might not have been detected as a Flutter project. Ensure that the folder that contains your pubspec.yaml is inside a VS Code Workspace Folder.

But it does not explain what a "VS Code Workspace Folder" is.  Can someone please tell me what my "VS Code Workspace Folder" is?  I can execute the app from VS Code.  So I don't know what to think.

[image]

UPDATE: I have stumbled onto the answer to my question and boy am I embarrassed.  All I needed to do was to click on the `{}` at the bottom of the VSCode window and all the info I needed was there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i have understood your question properly. Please correct me, if my interpretation if it's wrong.

As far as i have understood you want to know

1. what `vs code workspace folder is`
2. how to know the flutter version number
3. how to get device info ( I assume you are asking emulator on which this app works on)

Answers:

1. `VS code workspace folder`   is the folder where your flutter project exists.
2. You can type in `flutter --version` in the terminal to know flutter version number.
3. Type in `adb shell getprop` to get property of adb connected device

[image]